# jQuery.validator.methods.required()

Tags: jquery-validate

my code is :

```
$.validator.addMethod("dateBR", function dateBR(value, element) {

    return /^(?:(?:(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2]))\/(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))$|^(?:(?:(?:31\/0?[13578]|1[02])|(?:(?:29|30)\/(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])))\/(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))$|^(?:29\/0?2\/(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26]))))$/.test(value);
}
```

but I want to check it only if the Element is required ...
how can I do it ?

10X !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a class of 'required' to your element:

```
<input class='required' />
```

Then loop through the class names with:

```
$(this).attr('class').split(' ');
```